# Subviews position get changed on navigation to different view and coming back

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode5

I am working on Xcode5/iOS7. I have taken Tab-Bar based application with navigation controller on first tab. On first tab and first view, i am displaying search result in `UITableView` on search button click and then navigate from it to the next view. But when i come back its displaying me the search screen rather then showing me the search result.Anybody has any idea why its not restoring the position of subviews and making the whole screen looks like as it was at the time of loading for the first time.

regards,
V@run

Comment: put some code that how are you navigating ?

Comment: do you have constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution for my problem. We need to turn-Off Autolayout option under file inspector of view. You can do it by

View > Utilities > Show File Inspector, and un-select the “Use Autolayout” option

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using AutoLayout:

In the .xib file, select the VIEW and on the bottom-right menu, using AutoLayout, click in |-o-| symbol and select "Add Missing Constraints In View"

[image]